# d3js Pie Chart – text labels

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm creating a pie chart in d3 and want the name and value of a given slice to appear on hover:

```
@graph.append('path')
      .attr('d', @arc)
      .style('fill', (svg) => @color(svg.data.value))
      .attr('class', 'pie-slice')
      .on('mouseover', @pieSliceMouseOver)
      .on('mouseout', @pieSliceMouseOut)
      .append('text')
      .style('stroke', 'black')
      .append('textPath')
      .text((svg) -> "#{svg.data.name}: #{svg.data.value}")
```

This outputs the following (for one slice of the pie)

```
<path d="M-101.9924541587831,53.12757565208981A115,115 0 0,1 -2.1124459603436008e-14,-115L0,0Z" style="fill: #37823e;" class="pie-slice">
  <text style="stroke: #000000;">
    <textPath>401K: 82.28</textPath>
  </text>
</path>
```

But the text itself does not show. If I highlight the path node in Chrome, the browser correctly highlights the slice, but moving down to the text, the node isn't visible.

The mouseover and mouseout handlers work as designed, but the text simply does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic tooltip, you only need to append a `title` element to the element that you want to show the label for on mouseover. You don't even need to add an event handler for that, as browsers provide this functionality themselves.

You can use third-party libraries such as [tipsy](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy) if you need something fancier (example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ilyabo/1373263)).